# Tkinter Entry returns blank when called from another script but works fine by its self

Tags: python, tkinter

The is going to work like this:
Launcher with buttons to run different functions on other scripts. However when I try launching the "New Account" a new window pops up as it should but the entry field prints blank.

Launcher:

```
import Setup as s
import Stock as t
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

root.title("SWM Launcher")

welcome = Label(root, text = "Welcome to the Stock and Wastage Manager Launcher")
welcome.grid(row = 0, column =1, columnspan =3)

l1 = Label (root, text = "Please choose from the options below")
l1.grid(row = 1, column =1, columnspan =3)
    
submit = Button(root, text = "Open Account", command = lambda: program())
submit.grid(row = 3, column =1)

submit = Button(root, text = "New Account", command = lambda: s.setep())
submit.grid(row = 3, column =2)
```

What I'm trying to get to work from the setup script

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, window):
        window.title("SWM Account Maker")
        window.config(bg = "grey")
        window.geometry("800x900")

        self.searched = StringVar()
        name = Entry(window, width = 50, borderwidth = 5,textvariable=self.searched).grid(row = 2, column =1, columnspan =3)
        submit = Button(window, text = "Submit", command = lambda: self.name()).grid(row = 3, column =2)

    def name (self):
        works = self.searched.get()
        print(works)

def setep():
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The output i get from the print statement is blank yet if I run setup separately it works fine.I feel like I have miss understood something and no solution's I have found online work. also its my first project working with classes and Tkinter.

[image: The output I get]

Comment: It is because you have used multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Either change `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `setep()` function or change `self.searched = StringVar()` to `self.searched = StringVar(window)` inside `App.__init__()`.

Comment: That fixed it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have used multiple instances of Tk(). Either change Tk() to Toplevel() inside setep() function or change self.searched = StringVar() to self.searched = StringVar(window) inside App.**init**()